# SQL view join data in the same table but different row

Tags: performance, join, db2

Say I have single db2 table **FACT_VEHICLE** with the following rows:

---

```
FACT_VEHICLE
___________________________________________________________
**ID**    |**COLOR**   |**ADDITIONAL_INFO**
___________________________________________________________
1         |BLUE        |
___________________________________________________________
2         |RED         |1
```

From this table, I'm creating a view that should look like this:

```
VIEW_VEHICLE
____________________________________________________________
**ID**    |**COLOR_1** |**COLOR_2**
____________________________________________________________
1         |BLUE        |
____________________________________________________________
2         |RED         |BLUE
```

To display the content of the *COLOR_2* row in the view, I've thought about doing a subselect like this:

```
SELECT
f.ID AS ID,
f.COLOR AS COLOR_1,
f2.COLOR AS COLOR_2
FROM FACT_VEHICLE f JOIN FACT_VEHICLE f2 ON f2.ID = f.ADDITIONAL_INFO;
```

Is this the most performant way to do this?

Comment: Based on you data structure, i think it's the only way to do it (maybe you could create a view for a slight better performance). If you can have ADDITIONAL_INFO to null (which it seems you do, by the first row), you join can be a LEFT one, maybe intercepting those nulls with ISNULL function

Comment: Ah, yes - good point. ADDITIONAL_INFO can be null, a left join would be better.

Answer (score 0):

you have problem of null or value not present (excepted if you have a fk between 
ADDITIONAL_INFO  and ID on same table, with null enable of course)

```
SELECT f1.ID AS ID, f2.COLOR AS COLOR_1, ifnull(f2.COLOR, '') AS COLOR_2
FROM FACT_VEHICLE f1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN FACT_VEHICLE f2 ON f2.ID = f1.ADDITIONAL_INFO;
```